# WooCommerce Single Product Page, Can't customise anything

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am a bit new to creating websites, so go easy on me :)

I have created a webshop using the latest versions of wordpress, headway themes and woocommerce. Everything went fine, until I wanted to customise the single product pages. 
Obviously I used the visual editor of Headway Themes for all the other pages. But when I want to change anything on the Single Product page, no changes can be made whatsoever.

Upon installing woocommerce it created it's standard pages. I noticed that the single product page also does not have the same header as all the other pages (index, shop, etc) 
It has breadcrumbs at the very top of the page, but no header. I cannot add a header using the grid mode of Headway. It just doesn't let me change anything.

Anybody had any idea what I am doing wrong, or where I should be looking for answers ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try watching [Headway with AJ: Storefront: WooCommerce Screencast](http://headwaythemes.com/headway-with-aj-storefront-woocommerce-screencast/)

It looks like you need to have additional plugin to do stuff with woocommerce.